# Does a window lift motor have to be in a specific position when installing it?

Tags: replace, power-windows

When installing a replacement [window lift motor](http://shop.advanceautoparts.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_Window-Lift-Motor-Cardone_18040073-P_1326_R%7CGRP60022_1332626071____), do I have to worry about the motor being in a specific position (as far as rotation is concerned)?  Or does the motor stop at the top (closed position), and bottom (open position) based on resistance or something?

I know I will have to pay attention to where the motor engages the gear, but does the motor have set stop points?

I don't want to put the new motor in and have it smash the window as it tries to close it beyond the close position, or not close/open the window all the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever try rolling a power window up when it is already up? It tries, but it doesn't go anywhere--and nothing breaks. The answer is no; it does not matter where the output shaft/gear of the motor meshes with the driven gear.

Answer (score 0):

There are electronics (possibly integrated into the motor) that manages position and/or stall conditions (hitting travel limits).  You should be safe installing the motor without, "clocking" the system.